# How should I understand "the idea" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence, gre

The following is an excerpt from a GRE Verbal exercise:

> The hypothesis of an expanding Earth has never attracted notable support, and if it were not for the historical example of continental drift, such indifference might be a legitimate response to an apparently improbable concept. *It should be remembered, however, that drift too was once regarded as illusory, but **the idea** was kept alive until evidence from physicists compelled geologists to reinterpret their data.*

I don't understand what "the idea" in the sentence refers to. Does it mean the "drift theory" or the opinion that "drift is illusory"?

Comment: *The idea* is actually referring to *the hypothesis (or theory) of an expanding earth* of which *continental drift* is an example that supports that *theory or hypothesis*. *The idea* (of an expanding earth) was kept alive by physicists who forced geologists to reinterpret their data due to examples of *continental drift*.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: The excerpt makes no claim that "expanding earth" and "continental drift" have any connection other than that they were both originally regarded as "illusory" (the former still *is*, obviously). Thus *"the idea"* can only mean *the concept of continental drift*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*the idea* refers to the idea (or belief in this example) that continental drifts are a fact and that they indeed happened.